# will there be an update on MiscUtil for .Net 4?

Tags: .net

I was wondering about [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) maintained by Jon Skeet if I am not mistaken.
Will there be an update for .NET 4 or is the code moved somewhere else by now?
What I mean is that the solution type is for VS 2008 and the solution needs to be converted, which works but i was just wandering if that is already done in some place, for reasons of easy packaging I would prefer a wget "path to zipfile" & extract deployment, as our IT department is only 3 people, the less issue to worry about the better it is.
Its just a marginal issue, the library itself works fairly well so far.

Comment: Did you try compiling the source under .NET 4.0 and found any specific problems? I'd guess that it just works.

Comment: You're supposed to send the email to *Jon* Skeet.

Comment: The main page of the website that you link to gives his email address. His profile here on SO conveniently does as well. I suggest you email him and ask him; he might know.

Comment: What updates were you looking for, specifically?

Comment: maybe i wasn't precise in the first place. Edited question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, I haven't made any changes for .NET 4.

If there's demand for it, I can update the source zip to have two solution files - one for VS2008 and one for VS2010. At the moment I'm unlikely to do anything more than that. I haven't written any code for MiscUtil in quite a while - I'm spending my time on other projects like [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org).

Comment: ok :) but as I see there's many test classes, I presume the library is rather stable, isn't it?

Comment: Btw, that project looks really interesting :) With a good extension method management, one can really extend .NET beyond any dreams ^^

Comment: @Sebastian: It's reasonably stable... newer classes are rather more heavily tested than old ones :)

Comment: Hi Jon, please advice where can I find file saved in thread from miscutil, can't find it in bin folder, also can't find it in miscutil folder, if I specify file name only.

Comment: Noda Time is now to be found at [github.com/nodatime](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime)

Comment: @jdpilgrim: Updated to point at nodatime.org as the canonical URL.