# how to optimize data load from binary file

Tags: c#, .net, binary-data, endianness

I have a binary file encoded with little endian and containing ~250.000 values of var1 then another same number of values of var2. I should make a method that reads the file and returns a DataSet with those values in the columns var1 and var2.

I am using the library: [miscutil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) mentioned here in SO multiple times, see here as well for details: [will there be an update on MiscUtil for .Net 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374791/will-there-be-an-update-on-miscutil-for-net-4)

thanks a lot [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for making it available. :)

I have the following code working, I am interested in better ideas on how to minimize the for loops to read from the file and to populate the DataTable. Any suggestion?

```
private static DataSet parseBinaryFile(string filePath)
{
    var result = new DataSet();

    var table = result.Tables.Add("Data");

    table.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("rain", typeof(float));
    table.Columns.Add("gnum", typeof(float));

    const int samplesCount = 259200; // 720 * 360

    float[] vRain = new float[samplesCount];
    float[] vStations = new float[samplesCount];

    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath) || !File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unable to open the file: '{0}'", filePath));
        }

        // at this point FilePath is valid and exists...
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // We are using the library found here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/
            var reader = new MiscUtil.IO.EndianBinaryReader(MiscUtil.Conversion.LittleEndianBitConverter.Little, fs);

            int i = 0;

            while (reader.BaseStream.Position < reader.BaseStream.Length) //while (pos < length)
            {
                // Read Data

                float buffer = reader.ReadSingle();

                if (i < samplesCount)
                {
                    vRain[i] = buffer;
                }
                else
                {
                    vStations[i-samplesCount] = buffer;
                }

                ++i;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("number of reads was: {0}", (i/2).ToString("N0"));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < samplesCount; ++j)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { j + 1, vRain[j], vStations[j] });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "at this point FilePath is valid and exists..." Checking File.Exists and opening a file provides a window of opportunity for the file to not exist (race condition). You should skip the File.Exists test as it's redundant. Also, attempting to open it will produce FileNotFoundException which is much more descriptive than ArgumentException.

Comment: thanks Tergiver, will consider your input and refine my code.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1

Read the entire file into memory (or Memory Map it) and loop once.

Option #2

Add all the data table rows as you read the var1 section with a placeholder value for var2. Then fix-up the data table as you read the var2 section.